# Securely storing API credentials which need to be used as plain text

Tags: security

I have created an app which serves as a bridge between 2 different APIs - WebEx & Exchange Web Services - and Email. A user sends a calendar invitation to a special email address, the app parses the ICS and creates a WebEx Meeting, then connects to Exchange Web Services and puts the WebEx invitation information into the original invite.

This was created since WebEx does not have Mac Email/Calendar integration.

The rub is that to use WebEx API and Exchange API, I obviously need credentials for both APIs. I securely store the credentials with AES 256 bit encryption in the DB, but to access the APIs, I need original plain-text credentials (no oAuth or token support in APIs). They are securely transmitted over SSL, of course.

The security risk is not in having the passwords stolen as encryption keys are stored safely. The issue I am looking to address is the fact that customers fear their enterprise credentials are now stored in a manner that allows someone with access to those keys -- me or someone on development team -- to decrypt their information and gain access to the credentials.

The value of the app is great -- it saves tons of time, but how can I protect against this fear, while still allowing for this approach to work?

Comment: Does your server call home and pass the credentials? If not, I don't see why customers would think that data they enter and store on their device is available to anyone else.

Comment: The credentials are stored, encrypted within the database used by the web-app. When an email is received, it is processed, then those stored credentials are used to act on the user's behalf with the WebEx and Exchange APIs.

Answer (score 0):

The reality is if your code needs to send the passwords then if a developer has the source code **and** the encrypted passwords they'll have access to the plain test passwords. The only way around this is to deny the development team access to the encrypted passwords and deny those with the encrypted passwords access to the source code. You accomplish this by keeping the dev team away from the production database.

The security risk is that you have access to the production database storing the keys. Eliminate that access and their concern should be eliminated. Provide a utility (desktop or web-based) that can be used to configure the keys - a good idea anyways since those passwords will need to be changed in the future.

Have the customer create a database and then point the app to the database through a connection string change. The customer can use the utility to set the passwords.

Comment: It would be nice if it were possible to somehow uniquely identify their email client, and use whatever identifying value was present as a part of the key...